# Quad-buffer OpenGL for 4.2 core-profile?

Tags: opengl

I'm developing a 3D stereoscopic OpenGL app specifically for Windows 7 and nVidia Quadro K5000 cards.  Rendering the scene from left and right-eye perspectives using glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT) and glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT) works fine, and the 3D effect is displayed nicely.

While this works, I'd like to use nVidia's nSight Graphics local debugging. However, I get the error "Cannot enter frame debugging. nSight only supports frame debugging for ... OpenGL 4.2. Reason: glDrawBuffer(bufs[i] = 0x00000402)"

If the calls to glDrawBuffer are removed, nSight local debugging works.

Going through the [OpenGL 4.2 spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec42.core.20120427.pdf), DrawBuffer is described in section 4.2.1

So, two questions:

1) Is there some other way (besides DrawBuffer) to specify BACK_RIGHT or BACK_LEFT buffers for drawing to quad-buffers?

2) Is nSight capable of doing frame-level debugging on quad-buffered stereoscopic setups?  If so, how?